# WebView.delegate = self ломает верстку

Tags: swift, делегаты, uiwebview

Имеется `WebView`, который должен отображать страницу из HTML-кода. (Через loadHTMLString). Мне нужно было сделать так, что бы при загрузке исполнялся определенный код, поэтому в `viewDidLoad` я добавил строку `webView.delegate = self`, добавил в класс контроллера `UIWebViewDelegate`, и добавил в сам класс функцию `webViewDidFinishLoad` и `webView(... shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, ...)`, но, запустив программу, я увидел, что куда-то слетел весь CSS. Убрал строку с `delegate`, все вернулось на место, но перестал вызываться метод `webViewDidFinishLoad`... Весь интернет перерыл, ничего по этой теме не нашел... Что делать? Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Вы просили предоставить код делегата. Я решил предоставить весь код, лишь обрезал то, что точно никак не влияет на проблему, и, по привычке, прокомментировал все на английском =) Надеюсь на вашу помощь: http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/58850ee5b90d0e34734a8f27

Comment: покажите какой код выполняется в методах делегата

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Код делегата? Вы имеете в виду код класса контроллера?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Только ради вас =)

Comment: вы может весь проект на гитхаб выкиньте

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Это, по сути, и есть весь проект. Все остальное - так, опционально. К тому же, боюсь, что закидают тапками за мой нубокод.

Comment: ну дело ваше. если бы я мог скомпилировать и запустить было бы проще. короче, что вам надо делать - делегат сам по себе css испортить не может. Попробуйте закомментировать одну за одной строки в shouldStartLoading и смотрите какая вызывает проблему

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Первое, что пришло в голову. Ошибку вызывает строка с delegate

Comment: если делегат установлен, но все его методы пустые, ошибка все равно есть?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, Да.

Comment: ну тогда показывайте весь проект

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Тапками, пожалуйста, не кидаться ;) http://файлообменник.рф/zreko082s4qw.html

Comment: ладно, хрен с ним с гитхабом, но какой то нормальный обменник без ожидания 10 минут можно было найти

Comment: а что делать то, чтоб ваш webView увидеть. пишет "нет ошибок..." и все

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko нажать на кнопку в браузере, и дважды переключиться на вкладку "консоль". Сама строка с делегатом находится в файле "ConsoleViewController"

Comment: написано "кнопка успешно нажата" и время. что то еще там должно быть?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, Нет, все верно. А теперь попробуйте раскомментировать стооку с делегатом и проделать те же действия.

Comment: попробовал - все работает. shouldStart вызывается, didLoad не ызывается. все красиво

Comment: У вас не происходит такого? http://i.imgur.com/8Ebg2xy.png

Comment: да, именно это я и вижу. а в чем проблема?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, Проблема в том, что должно быть так: http://i.imgur.com/rwu15o6.png. Если закомментировать строку с делегатом, CSS вдруг просыпается, и выдает нормальную картинку.

Comment: ааа. тогда вы всегда возвращаете return false в `shouldStartLoadWith` то есть что бы вы там не пытались грузить никогда не загрузится. попробуйте возвращать false в `if(request.url?.scheme=="t")` и true снаружи

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, ура! Заработало! Напишите ответ, дам галочку ;)

Comment: написать ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В своем коде, вы всегда возвращаете false при попытке начать грузить новую страницу в webView. Вам надо возвращеть false в if  и true снаружи

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if(request.url?.scheme=="t")
    {
        var str = request.url?.query
        str = str!.substring(from: (str!.characters.index(str!.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)))
        ((self.parent as! TabBarViewController).customizableViewControllers![1] as! WebViewController).filePreviewObject.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "console.EasyHTML.consoleMessages[\(str!)][5]=!console.EasyHTML.consoleMessages[\(str!)][5]")
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```